Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Problems after upgrading at 23.10
After the upgrade from 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04, I get the error message when starting user interfaces programmed with GTK4:
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen

The programs themselves work nonetheless smoothly.
Does anyone have an idea or explanation?

@David Are you sure? Wasn't Lunar Lobster name given to 23.04? Holger, I believe there is no direct way to upgrade to 24.04 from 23.04. Did you upgrade to 23.10 first?

You are right on both counts there is no direct way to upgrade to 24.04 from 23.04 and after January 25, 2024 the path to upgrade from 23.04 to any version would have been gone as it had reached EOL. Thanks for the correction.

You had right, The mistake devil had struck.

After a long search, I found a solution.
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

An environment variable must therefore be set. Of course, this can also be registered in the .bashrc.
